# Где ошибка в выводе словаря в чат discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

единственное сообщение в канале с ID - 1082311110176280627 должно редактироваться каждые две секунды на переменную carstake вывод должен быть без кавычек и скобок, двоеточие должно остаться! Вывод будет в строчку ниже приведены примеры

```
carstake={"Автомобили":"кем они заняты"}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global a
    global carstake
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'!cavalli', type = discord.ActivityType.playing))
    chann = bot.get_channel(1082311110176280627)
    await chann.purge()
    carmsg = await chann.send("A")
    while True:
        for key in carstake.items():
            await carmsg.edit(content = "{0}: {1}".format(key,value))
        time.sleep(2)
```

При запуске выдает в предпоследней строчке:

```
await carmsg.edit(content = "{0}: {1}".format(key,value))
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

Должно быть так: сообщение должно редактироваться каждые 2 секунды и писать словарь carstake без скобок и кавычек просто допустим Muxa:rs7
Хочу написать на базе этого
Учтите что словарь carstake будет изменяться при работе дискорд бота

```
import time
t = {'Muxa':'rs7', 'nedetvora':'rs6'}
while True:
    for key, value in t.items():
        
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key,value))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Примерный результат редактированного сообщения:
Автомобили: и кем они заняты
Muxa:rs7
nedetvora:rs6

Answer (score 0):

Создадим переменную `cars`, для примера:

```
cars = {"Автомобиль 1":"Что-то", "Автомобиль 2": "Что-то"}
```

Отправляем сообщение в нужный Вам канал:

```
channel = ...
message = await channel.send("Тест")
```

Теперь создадим цикл:

```
while True:
    for car in cars.items():
```

Используя переменную `key` вытаскиваем значения из `cars`:

```
        await message.edit(content = f"{car[0]}: {car[1]}")
        await asyncio.sleep(2) #советую использовать asyncio.sleep
```

В **python** индекс начинается с ***0***, соответственно:

> **car[0]** — значение из переменной `cars`: "Автомобиль 1"

> **car[1]** — значение из переменной `Автомобиль 1`: "Что-то"

***Полный код:***

```
cars = {"Автомобиль 1":"Что-то", "Автомобиль 2": "Что-то"}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = ...
    message = await channel.send("Тест")
    while True:
        for car in cars.items():
            await message.edit(content = f"{car[0]}: {car[1]}")
            await asyncio.sleep(2) #советую использовать asyncio.sleep
```

***Что получилось:***
[image: Что получилось]

Comment: dictionary changed size during iteration 
ему не нравиться что во время работы, менется размер словаря как решить ?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю. У меня сработали без проблем.